# Efficient way to get unique elements from a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector of pairs of integers that looks somehow like that:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 9)
(2, 3)
(6, 1)
(4, 0)
```

I want to extract unique elements from there, so that the result looks as follows:
`‍‍0‍, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 4`
(basically just all numbers without duplicates)

At the moment I'm doing it like that:

```
std::vector<int> getElements(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> S) {
    std::vector<int> V;
    for (std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator i = S.begin(); i != S.end(); i++) {
        if (std::find(V.begin(), V.end(), i->first) == V.end()) {
            V.push_back(i->first);
        }
        if (std::find(V.begin(), V.end(), i->second) == V.end()) {
            V.push_back(i->second);
        }
    }
    return V;
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Comment: use `set` or `map`.

Comment: Do you care about order?

Comment: @clcto no, order doesn't matter

Comment: @vgeclair  You can make the function more efficient if at least the parameter will be declared like const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current solution is `O(n^2)`. You can reduce the *linear-scan* for already seen elements to an amortized `O(1)` by using `std::unordered_set` to store the already seen numbers; This will improve your runtime to `O(n)`.

Here is an improved algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> getElements(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> S) {
    std::unordered_set<int> ss;
    std::for_each(S.begin(), S.end(), [&ss](const auto& p) {
        ss.insert(p.first);
        ss.insert(p.second);
    });
    return std::vector<int>(ss.begin(), ss.end());
}
```

See an example [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f44675fc47826a4)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any more efficient way to do it?

Yes, there is. `std::find` has O(n) complexity for vector, so repeating it for each element gives you O(n*n) complexity.

A simple alternative is to add every element into `std::set`. The complexity of building the set is O(n log n).

Answer (score 3):

Not measured, but I think it is faster...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getElements(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& S) {
    std::vector<int> V;
    V.reserve(2*S.size());
    for (const auto& i : S) {
        V.push_back(i.first);
        V.push_back(i.second);
    }
    std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
    V.erase(std::unique(V.begin(), V.end()), V.end()); 
    return V;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{{0, 1},{1, 9},{2, 3},{6, 1},{4, 0}};

    for(const auto& i : getElements(v))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```